# Z-index does not work with datetimepicker django widgets

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I used [this](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/) date time picker.

**I found that z-index doesn't work and date time popups is hidden under a div**.

I found that the problem is due to class **"table-responsive"**.

This is my code:

```
<form>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- my datetimepicker fields  -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried with this jquery codes:

```
$(document).on('focusin','#'+inputId,function (){console.log($(this).parentsUntil('div.table-responsive').last());$(this).parentsUntil('div.table-responsive').last().parent().css('overflow-x','visible') });
    $(document).on('focusout','#'+inputId,function (){$(this).parentsUntil('div.table-responsive').last().parent().css('overflow-x','scroll') });
```

This solve the problem if there is not x overflow.
If there is x-overflow the date input is hidden due to overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace date piker js file with [this](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/files/3854400/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.txt) files and the problem was solved.